# Uncaught Error: The Alan Button instance has already been created. There cannot be two Alan Button instances created at the same time

Tags: reactjs, alan

I'm building an ecommerce store with a AI button using Alan AI.Ikeep getting the above error and I used [Alan AI Error Uncaught Error: The Alan Button instance has already been created. There cannot be two Alan Button instances created at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548257/alan-ai-error-uncaught-error-the-alan-button-instance-has-already-been-created) but my code is still broken.Can anyone help me to see where I am going wrong. I want to be able to see my menu items when I use the button.Thanks

````
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import alanBtn from '@alan-ai/alan-sdk-web';



function App () {

  const[cart,setCart]= useState([])
  const [menuItems,setMenuItems] = useState([])

const Alan = () =>{
// // this shows the  AI button
useEffect(() => {
  function updateScreen(time) {
  alanBtn({
      key: '',
      onCommand: ({commandData}) => {
        if (commandData.command === 'getMenu') {
          // Call the client code that will react to the received command
        }
      }
    
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(updateScreen);
}},[]);



  const addToCart =(menuItem)=>{
    setCart((oldCart)=>{
      return [...oldCart, menuItem]
    })
  }



  return( <div className = "App"> 

  {menuItems.map((menuItem) =>(

    <li key = {menuItem.name}>
              {menuItem.name} - ${menuItem.price} -{menuItem.category}
              <button onClick={()=> addToCart(menuItem)}>add to cart</button>
    </li>

  ))}

  <div>
  <h2>Cart</h2>
  </div>

  {cart.map((cartItem) => (
    <li key ={cartItem.name}>
      {cartItem.name} - {cartItem.price} - {cartItem.category}
    </li>
    
  ))}
  </div>
  )}

   
};

export default App;```
````

Comment: @MdShahjalal do you think you could help?